# warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’

Tags: object-oriented

I am new to C++, and upon running this code I am getting the following error, can someone please explain what's wrong with the code? [image: code of class declaration and object instantiation]Thank you.

main.cpp:8:17: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
8 |     C(char *s = " ",int i =0, double d=1){

Comment: The error message says it: you may not pass a string constant using a pointer to non-const.

Comment: Can you further elaborate on what it means ?

Comment: What do you know about the const attribute ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, I am completely new to this.

Comment: Use `const char* s` then.

Comment: Hi , I used it and the error is gone , but now it says " /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: Read the error message. It is about  `main`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, raw strings (not to be confused with the `std::string` class) are stored by placing the characters in consecutive memory locations, followed by a null-byte terminator. Then to reference a string you simply use a pointer to the first character, hence its type is `char *`.

String literals are stored in your compiled binary and can be shared among multiple occurrences. As such they should be treated as immutable, i.e., each character is logically of type `const char` and the corresponding pointer is of type `const char*`.

The compiler is warning you that are using a variable of type `char*` instead of `const char*`.
To see why this is problematic consider the following snippet of code:

```
char *mystring1 = "Hello world!";
const char *mystring2 = "Hello world!";
*mystring1 = 'B';
std::cout << mystring1 << "\n" << mystring2 << std::endl;
```

What should this print?
If the string "Hello world!" is stored only once the, the assignment would modify it and the `std::cout` statement would output

```
Jello world!
Jello world!
```

Instead of the expected (?):

```
Jello world!
Hello world!
```

Besides, it's likely that your program won't even have write access to the memory area used to store the string literal, resulting in a memory access violation.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.